# hostapd.conf missing in /etc/hostapd/

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, raspberrypi, hostapd

I was following [this](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-wifi-extender/) tutorial to setup my Raspberry Pi4 as wifi extender in a  Ubuntu Server 22.04, in the step 8, where the tutorial asks me to adjust `hostapd` configuration in `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`, I noticed that hostapd.conf does not exist in /etc/hostapd, am I missing something?
I tried checking if `hostapd` is installed, and obtive this:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/hostapd$ sudo apt install hostapd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
hostapd is already the newest version (2:2.10-6ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: you can cp an example file from `/usr/share/doc/hostapd/examples/hostapd.conf` or write it on your own.

Comment: Idk what to write in a hostapd.conf file, but thanks for help, I’ll copy from the path you mentioned.                           Btw, do I have to change something in the file there in the examples, or can I use it as is, and follow the tutorial I mentioned in my post?

Comment: sorry with the configuration I can not help.

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages **you** got on **your system**. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: The only error I received was ```ubuntu dnsmasq[2339]: dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for port 53: Address already in use
ubuntu dnsmasq[2339]: failed to create listening socket for port 53: Address already in use
Jul 16 10:43:35 ubuntu dnsmasq[2339]: FAILED to start up
Jul 16 10:43:35 ubuntu systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Jul 16 10:43:35 ubuntu systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 16 10:43:35 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.```

Comment: But I fixed that already by changing dnsmasq listening port to 5353

Answer (score 0):

The hostapd-package does not provide a `hostapd.conf` in `/etc/hostapd/`, you need to create your own. But there are examples.
You can start by copying `/usr/share/doc/hostapd/examples/hostapd.conf` to `/etc/hostapd`:

```sh
sudo cp /usr/share/doc/hostapd/examples/hostapd.conf /etc/hostapd/
```

You will need to modify it. The example contains a lot of comments that explain the file.
You also might want to read the docs at `/usr/share/doc/hostapd/`, but to start the comments in the example should be fine.

More examples can be found here:
https://github.com/morrownr/USB-WiFi/tree/main/home/AP_Mode
These do not include so much detailed comments, but a few different examples for different needs.